# Change Dropdown selection function to Bullet check option

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes, dropdown

name;
            $adv_actions_value1 = mb_strtolower ( str_replace(' ', '-', $adv_actions_value1) );
        }else{

            $adv_actions_value=esc_html__('Property Types','wpresidence');
            //$adv_actions_value=wpresidence_return_custom_dropdown_label_type10('types');
            $adv_actions_value1='all';
        }

        print'
        
            
                
                    '.$adv_actions_value.'
                 
                
                
                    '.$action_select_list.'
                
            
        ';
        ?>

Change Dropdown selection function to Bullet check option, something like Ref https://prnt.sc/1wbixn9

Comment: Please don’t just post code. Please explain the problem, what you tried, what you expected, and what the result was.

Comment: I want to Change Dropdown selection function to Bullet check option, something like Ref https://prnt.sc/1wbixn9

Comment: So instead of an HTML `select` you want an `input` with a type of `radio`?